# nth-child direct child on nested lists

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can't find a solution for this problem represented on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctvzLovr/). 
I have a list and inside that list I have another list with items. I want to select the second direct child of the first list but what happens is that the second element on the second list is selected too. How can I select only the direct 2nd child of the first list?

```
<ul id="list-1">
    <li>Item 1
        <ul id="list-2">
            <li>Item 1 Child 1</li>
            <li>Item 1 Child 2 (I don't want this one to be red)</li>
        </ul> 
    </li>
    <li>Item 2 (I only want this one to be red)</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I'm currently trying to access it like this: `$("#list-1 li:nth-child(2)").css("color", "red");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the direct descendant selector, `>`:

```
$("#list-1 > li:nth-child(2)").css("color", "red");
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ctvzLovr/1/)

Comment: Exactly that. Thank you.